# Converting a Project into Library Project with Libs and Gradle Configurations

Tags: android, gradle, library-project

I have an Android project which contains around 15 Dependencies so there are 20 entries in App Gradle file and 20 Libs in library folder plus some Java classes. This project is working fine for me but I need to use it in my other many projects. The problem is I am not able to convert my project into library project I have followed many tutorials and read many articles but I am not able to convert my project into Library project with Dependancies and AARs included.

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation(name: 'admob-mediation', ext: 'aar')
implementation(name:'adcolony-mediation', ext:'aar')
implementation(name:'unityads-mediation', ext:'aar')
implementation(name:'UnityAds', ext:'aar')
implementation(name:'ironsource-mediation', ext:'aar')
implementation(name:'applovin-mediation', ext:'aar')
implementation(name:'applovin-sdk-9.7.2', ext:'aar')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation(name:'vungle-mediation', ext:'aar')

}
```

Here is snapshot from libs folder
[image]

I am stuck here and I am not able to move forward from here, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: I am not able to export library project, I keep trying creating the build it does nothin, and I cannot find an option for Library in Gradle configuration from Right Hand side panel